# Seeding tables with one to many relationship EF code first

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to seed some database tables that have a one to many relationship. Using the code first approach with the Entity Framework. Somehow the foreign keys remain empty in the database table activities, column UserId.

Why isn't this working?

```
        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
          u => u.FirstName,
           new User { Id = 1, FirstName = "Trees", Preposition = "de", LastName = "Vries", EmailAddress = "trees@test.com", PhoneNumber = 0684637485, Password = "test123", RoleId = 1 }
         );
        context.SaveChanges();


        context.Activities.AddOrUpdate(
            a => a.Name,
            new Activity
            {
                Name = "Metselen van de binnenplaats",
                Comment = "Voorbeeld commentaar regel 1.",
                Start = DateTime.Now,
                End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5),
            },//etc.
            );
        context.SaveChanges();

        var randomActivities = (from s in context.Activities select s).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(6).ToList();

        context.Users.AddOrUpdate(
          u => u.Id,
           new User { Id = 1, Activities = randomActivities }
         );
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Edit: Solution

After a few hours of wrestling with the code I finally managed to get it all working (without having to add foreign keys to the model classes).

I will share the code and some discoveries so others might benefit from it.

A few things to keep in mind.

Code directly to the context!

This does not work:

```
   List<Activity> randomActivities = (from s in context.Activities select s).OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).ToList(); //Does not work
```

Works:

```
List<Activity> randomActivities = context.Activities.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).ToList();
```

Only call SaveChanges() when you need to link objects that already need to be in the tables.

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

And Finally, you can create the data with a relationship to other tables, simple by adding a new List into it (see code below for details).

The seed method looks like this now:

```
 var users = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                FirstName = "Trees", 
                Preposition = "de", 
                LastName = "Vries", 
                EmailAddress = "trees@test.com", 
                PhoneNumber = 0684637485, 
                Password = "test123",
                Activities =
                new List<Activity> { // <-- Like this!
                    new Activity { Name = "Boren muren in de grote hal 1", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5) },
                    new Activity { Name = "Vloer schuren 1", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) },
                    new Activity { Name = "Boren muren in de grote hal 2", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(5) },
                    new Activity { Name = "Vloer schuren 2", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) }
                },
                Messages =
                new List<Message>
                {
                    new Message { Subject = "Test onderwerp van bericht 1", Body = "Tekst van het bericht 1", AuthorId = 3 },
                    new Message { Subject = "Test onderwerp van bericht 2", Body = "Tekst van het bericht 2", AuthorId = 3 },
                    new Message { Subject = "Test onderwerp van bericht 3", Body = "Tekst van het bericht 3", AuthorId = 3 }
                }
            },
            new User { FirstName = "Jaap", LastName = "Winter", EmailAddress = "jaap@test.com", PhoneNumber = 0628305643, Password = "test123"  },
            new User { FirstName = "Klaas", LastName = "Janssen", EmailAddress = "klaas@test.com", PhoneNumber = 0639453321, Password = "test123" }
        };
        users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(r => r.FirstName, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        List<Activity> randomActivities = context.Activities.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).ToList();
        var projects = new List<Project>
        {
            new Project { Name = "Test project", Description = "Omschrijving van test project 1.", Start = DateTime.Now, End = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10), User = context.Users.Single(s => s.FirstName == "Trees"), Activities = randomActivities }
        };
        projects.ForEach(s => context.Projects.AddOrUpdate(r => r.Name, s));
```

Activity model class:

```
    public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

User model class:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Preposition { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public Role Role { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: The foreign-keys of *what* remain empty?

Comment: Of the relationship Activities.UserId - Users.Id

Comment: I don't see you're adding a reference to `User` from your `Activity`. Perhaps showing `Activity` class will help.

Comment: It remains empty because you don't put any value in it. When creating new `Activity` you need to add reference to `User` (through `UserId` in your case): `new Activity { UserId = user.Id, ...  }`.

Comment: I was kinda hoping that the EF would understand the relationship when I added an array with Activity objects to the user object. So I guess I need to hard code the foreign keys while seeding?

Comment: EF would have them mapped automatically if you were to add a reference to `User` and not only exposing the foreign-key (`UserId`). If you don't want to add a reference to `User`, you'll have to map them manually.

Comment: Yes. I should be able to do just this in the user model, right? public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; } Instead of adding a UserId int to the Activity class.

Comment: Your current code shows that you already have defined `User.Activities`. I meant `public virtual User User { get; set; }` in `Activity`.

Comment: Added my solution to the post.